# How to allow for multiple file names when searching through a directory in python?

Tags: python, string, directory, operating-system, sys

How can I write something like:

```
module_path = os.path.join(root_dir,_dir,'Tests.py')
```

to be able to also take into considerations files named Test.py and test.py and tests.py?

If the file Tests.py isn't found, how can it check for another of the two to make sure that who ever wrote the program gets their file seen?

What I am trying to say is is there something that would allow me to do this?:

```
module_path = os.path.join(root_dir,_dir,'(T or t)est(s).py')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is literally those four files you are searching for then something like the following will work:

```
import os

_dir = 'test'
names=['Test.py','test.py','Tests.py','tests.py']

for fname in names:
    test_path = os.path.join(_dir, fname)
    if os.path.isfile(test_path):
        module_path = test_path
        break
```

You will need to modify to suit your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), which supports a *simple* version of regular expressions ("Unix-style wildcards"). E.g., you can use this:

```
for name in glob.glob("[tT]est*.py"):
    print("I found", name)
```

This matches files whose name *begins* with "Test" or "test", and ends with `.py`. It won't give you the names in order of preference, but it might be all you need.